# How would I do this query in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

So let's say I have three models: `User`, `CarBrand`, `CarModel`, `CarCharacteristics`. The `CarCharacteristics` model describes how a user rates the characteristics of a car. So there can be many `CarCharacteristics` objects for a user, and a user can have many `CarCharacteristics`.

This is what my models look like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class CarBrand(models.Model):
    idcar_brand = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class CarModel(models.Model):
    idcar_model = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    car_brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrand, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class CarCharacteristics(models.Model):
    idcar_characteristics = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

What I would like to do is to get all `CarBrand` objects where a `User` has a `CarCharacteristics`. This is what am I doing right now:

```
car_chars = CarCharacteristics.objects.filter(user=user_id)
car_brands_ids = []
for car_char in car_chars:
    brand_id = car_char.car_model.car_brand.idcar_brand
    if brand_id not in car_brands_ids:
        car_brands_ids.append(brand_id)
brands = CarBrand.objects.filter(idcar_brand__in=brand_ids)
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this? And how do I get all the `CarModels` where there exists a `CarCharacteristics`?

Comment: So did the answers prove to be useful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I think this works:

```
user_id = request.user.pk
brands = CarBrand.objects.exclude(~Q(carmodel__carcharacteristics__user=user_id))
```

**EDIT**

Is what I have above also equivalent to this:

```
user_id = request.user.pk
car_models = CarModel.objects.filter(carcharacteristics__user=user_id)
brands = CarBrand.objects.filter(carmodel__in=car_models).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CarBrand.objects.exclude(carmodel__carcharacteristics__user=None).distinct()
```

Comment: So what exactly does that do?

Answer (score 0):

```
CarBrand.objects.filter(carmodel__carcharacteristics__user=request.user).distinct()
```